# Input tags not binding to case sensitive JSON keys in Ember.js

Tags: json, ember.js, handlebars.js

My data model is received from an external system that uses camel case for JSON keys.  Everything seems to display fine in Ember.js except the data does not bind in edit mode.  To easily recreate the problem, I've adapted one of the Ember.js starting projects using the following JSON:

```
var posts = [{
  Id: '1',
  Title: "Coats save lives",
  Author: { Name: "blogger" },
  PostDate: new Date('11-22-2013'),
  Excerpt: "My second blog post.",
  Body: "Be sure to wear a coat in cold weather."
}, {
  Id: '2',
  Title: "Hats are useful",
  Author: { Name: "blogger" },
  PostDate: new Date('12-05-2013'),
  Excerpt: "My first blog post.",
  Body: "Hats keep your head warm."  
}];
```

The view template works fine.  However, the following edit template does not bind with the model and displays empty input forms:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post/_edit">
  <p>{{input type="text" value=Title}}</p>
  <p>{{input type="text" value=Excerpt}}</p>
  <p>{{textarea value=Body}}</p>
</script>
```

Comment: What does your edit route object look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Capitalized properties signifies global namespace in handlebars, to workaround this you can fully qualify the reference `model.Title` or use lower case properties.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/afIYApU/1/edit